# BB_NO_NETWORK access for yocto per layer. Mirror external repositories and access local repositories

Tags: yocto, bitbake

Our development is behind a firewall with no access to the internet. We created a local mirror of all the packages we require using a network accessed machine. The mirror is made available behind the firewall and our yocto accesses this mirror for the packages. `BB_NO_NETWORK` is set to prevent any updates being pulled.

We also have a number of local git repositories with our own code that we would like to access. These are however blocked by `BB_NO_NETWORK`. Is there a way to configure the layers such that the `BB_NO_NETWORK` (or `BB_FETCH_PREMIRRORONLY`) variable is relevant per layer or per recipe? Otherwise an alternative method would also be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use [BB_ALLOWED_NETWORKS](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/latest/ref-manual/ref-manual.html#var-BB_ALLOWED_NETWORKS)

> Specifies a space-delimited list of hosts that the fetcher is allowed to use to obtain the required source code

Comment: I do see that the BB_ALLOWED_NETWORKS only works if BB_NO_NETWORK is disabled. So the correct way of working is to use BB_NO_NETWORKS if you want to block all and BB_ALLOWED_NETWORKS if you want a whitelist. The documentation does state that the mirror will still be used for packages that are not in the whitelist but in the mirror.